# get genfromtxt/loadtxt to ignore datatype in ignored columns/rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file with integer data, where the first few lines/columns are used for names.

I'd like to be able to use `genfromtxt` or `loadtxt` and still get numpy to read it as a homogenous array. To do this I used the options `skiprows` and `usecols` but it did not help.
In the (working) example below I'd expect `print(test_array.shape)` to give (3,3) and `print(test.array)` to give

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want without trimming the first rows/columns with a unix tool before attempting to load the file? Note that the actual files I want to load are B-I-G (~6 gigs) so any solution should not be too computationally intensive.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from StringIO import StringIO #use io.StringIO with py3
import numpy as np

example_file = StringIO("FID 1 2 3\n11464_ATCACG 0 0 0\n11465_CGATGT 0 1 0\n11466_TTAGGC 1 0 0")
test_array = np.loadtxt(example_file, skiprows=1, usecols=(1,), dtype=int)

print(test_array.shape) #(3,)
print(test_array) #[0 0 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `usecols` and `skip_header` flags in `np.genfromtxt`. Then it works fine as:

```
test_array = np.genfromtxt(example_file, skip_header=1, usecols=(1,2,3))
>>> print(test_array)
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```